# Spring JPA with nested relation but just need 1 depth relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I made 2 depth relations for `MainBranch` model and when I get the `MainBranch` it will get `SubBranch` and `SubBranchRef`. I need to get just `MainBranch` with `SubBranch`. What should I do about this problem?

```
public class MainBranch{

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainBranch")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<SubBranch> subBranchs = new ArrayList<>();
}


public class SubBranch{
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_branch_id", nullable = false)
    private MainBranch mainBranch;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subBranch")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<SubBranchRef> subBranchRef = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class SubBranchRef{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_branch_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private SubBranch subBranch;

    @Column(name = "ref_data", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String refData;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `FetchType.LAZY` for `SubBranchRef` in `SubBranch entity`:

By making the FetchType as LAZY, this would not load `SubBranchRef` when we fetch the `SubBranch`.

```java
public class SubBranch{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subBranch", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<SubBranchRef> subBranchRef = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on **subBranchs** in **MainBranch**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainBranch")
@JsonManagedReference
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"subBranchRef"}, allowSetters = true)
private List<SubBranch> subBranchs = new ArrayList<>();
```